# Simple linked list ques

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

So in the first code, I am making a.next=b. Which means both a.next and b acts as a reference to Node6. SO when I am making b=None.. Why is a.next still pointing to Node6,

In the second code, when I am aking c=a, both c and a are references to Node 5. Now I am making c.next=None, But this change is being reflected to a also. even a.next becomes None.

BOTH THE CODE I MADE SAME STEPS, Why is the change only reflected in code 2?

```
class Node:

     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.next = None

a=Node(5)
b=Node(6)
a.next=b
b=None
while a is not None:
    print(a.val)
    a=a.next
```

CODE 2

```
class Node:
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.next = None

a=Node(5)
b=Node(6)
a.next=b
c=a
c.next=None
while a is not None:
    print(a.val)
    a=a.next
```

Comment: WHen I make c.next=None... Why does a.next also become None? I am doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: When you make `c=a`, you are not passing the values of a but the reference to a. So from there, c will refer to the same object as a refers to.

Comment: In the first code, even a.next refers the same as b right? Node6 in both. Then why isnt it changing?

Comment: @NeverGiveUp, cause you don't change it. `b` stores reference to object. `a.next` stores reference to dame object. You just null reference, not an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain using a diagrammatic representation:
[image]

In case 1: List `a` has two nodes 5, and 6 in linked list.
But In case 2: List `a` and `c` have one node 5 in linked list. And another linked list is pointed by `b` which has only 6.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

NOTE:
- Since a,b, c are pointers storing addresses. When you execute `c.next=None`, the value of next at address pointed by `c` (also pointed by `a`) becomes None.

Answer (score 1):

You have a class `Node`. When you create an object of that class and assign it to a variable such as `a` or `b`, you are dynamically allocating memory large enough to hold the contents of the object and then assigning the *address* of that memory to the variable. So CODE 1 *really* looks more like:

```
addr1 = storage address for Node(5) // Statement 1
a = addr1 // Statement 2
addr2 = storage address for Node(6) // Statement 3
b = addr2 // Statement 4
a.next = b // Statement 5
b = None // Statement 6
```

Statement 5 is updating the `next` attribute of the Node that was allocated in Statement 1 with the value of `b`, which is `addr2`. In Statement 6, we are assigning a new value to `b`, but that will not change what was stored into the actual object referenced by `a`.  Consider the following example with integers:

```
x = 5
y = 7
x = y
y = 0
```

Setting `y = 0` doesn't affect the previous assignment of `x = y`, i.e. x will still have y's previous value of 7. The only difference i your example is that we are not dealing with integers but with addresses.

Now that we appreciate that `a` and `b` are really references to memory locations (i.e. addresses) that hold the actual objects, when you say `c=a`, c and a both refer now to the same object and can be used interchangeably. Thus, `c.next` and `a.next` refer to the same attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are storing `b` in `a.next`, so while iterating through linked list wit head node as `a` you traverse all the nodes.

But in the second case  `c` and `a` having the same refernce, and  `c.next` is `None` so whenever you traverse the linked list with head as `c` you get to only one node. As `while a is not None` condition not allowing to move for the next node.

Following code works as expected.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None


a = Node(5)
b = Node(6)
c = a
c.next = b #this line changed
while a is not None:
    print(a.val)
    a = a.next
```